# GPath to find if a table header contains a matching string

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I'm parsing an HTML file into a well-formed XML document using NekoHTML parser. However I can't quite figure out the GPath so that I can identify the table that has the "Settings" string.

```
def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
parser.setFeature('http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces', false)

    def html = 
    ''' 
        <html>
            <title>Hiya!</title>
        </html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='3'>Settings</th>
                    <td>First cell r1</td>
                    <td>Second cell r1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='3'>Other Settings</th>
                    <td>First cell r2</td>
                    <td>Second cell r2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    '''

    def slurper = new XmlSlurper(parser)
    def page = slurper.parseText(html)
```

In this sample, the first table should be selected so that I can iterate over other row values in it. Can someone help me with this GPath please?

EDIT: Side question - why does

```
println page.HTML.HEAD.TITLE
```

print an empty string, shouldn't it return the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the table with 'Settings' in the header, you should be able to do:

   ```
   def settingsTableNode = page.BODY.TABLE.find { table ->
     table.TBODY.TR.TH.text() == 'Settings'
   }
   ```
2. `page` points to the root of the document, so you don't need the `HTML`.  All you should need to do is:

   ```
   println page.HEAD.TITLE
   ```